# PHP - Is there any concern with using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "pathname" on every page that needs to include another file?

Tags: php, file, path, include

Due to path issues, I changed my php site to have the following statement at least once on each page:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/file.php");
```

Are there any concerns (mainly security) that I should have using this approach?

(before I just used: `include("/path/file.php");` )

Comment: The only difference I can see is it is easier to move a site with DOCUMENT_ROOT to another servers directory than using the absolute full path in your second example. On the other hand if you want to run it from command line, DOCUMENT_ROOT is not set.

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT returns the location off the root folder for your webserver. For as far as I know this shouldn't cause any issues security wise.

Comment: Yes, they are equal out of a security perspective. Migration is easier with the first one. A third way is to use relative paths like `include( '../path/file.php' );`, though it gets tricky when including a file wich includes another file...

Comment: you can also define a constant.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm assuming the only time the user could see the full path (if that matters) is if errors are set to be outputted. @HasseBjörk I switched from relative paths for just that reason... it got too complex and I kept getting errors. (I'm not a pro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As PHP is parsed exclusively on the server, using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will never be passed to the client and doesn't create a security issue.

However, like all `$_SERVER` variables, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is only made available by your webserver and running these scripts in a command line environment will cause an undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of any concerns when using that, but I prefer doing this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/path/to/file/from/current/filephp";
```

I do this, because we don't always know if there will be a document root, but we do know that the current file does have a current directory.

Comment: but if you do this from file in a subfolder the `__DIR__` will _not_ be the document root, but instead the folder where the file sits.